# Получить длину видео внутри скрипта ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

Я налаживаю видео `1.mp4` на `background.mp4`
для этого использую эту команду:

```
ffmpeg -i background.mp4 -vf "movie=1.mp4[inner]; [in][inner] overlay [out]" completed.mp4
```

Мне нужно чтобы видео было такой же длины как и `1.mp4`
Вручную я бы мог указать продолжительность видео `-t 00:00:25`.
Можно ли вместо цифр `00:00:25` указать продолжительность `1.mp4`
Или как по-другому можно сделать `completed.mp4` такой-же продолжительностью как `1.mp4`.

Comment: Вы можете вычислить длину с помощью `ffprobe` и подставить ее как аргумент `ffmpeg`.

Comment: @Iliaw495Nikitin дайте пожалуйста пример как этосделать и подставить аргумент. Буду благодарен.